# Django cant find templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

So ive been trying to setup a django settings module that will check the environment variable and load settings.

Heres what my settings module looks like

```
/templates
    home.html

/settings
    base.py
    prod.py
    dev.py
    test.py
```

base.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),
]

urls.py

from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r"^$", direct_to_template, {'template' : 'home.html' }, name="home"),
)
```

When I had all of my settings in one file, this worked just fine, but since I split the files up I get the error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

home.html

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/Users/Tulsa/Apps/tulsa-applications-co/tulsa/tulsa/settings/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Users/Tulsa/.Apps/tulsa_io/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/Users/Tulsa/.Apps/tulsa_io/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/Users/Tulsa/.Apps/tulsa_io/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/Users/Tulsa/.Apps/tulsa_io/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/Users/Tulsa/.Apps/tulsa_io/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pagination/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/Users/Tulsa/.Apps/tulsa_io/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangosaml2/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/Users/Tulsa/Apps/tulsa-applications-co/tulsa/tulsa/apps/profiles/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/Users/Tulsa/.Apps/tulsa_io/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/templates/home.html (File does not exist)

Using loader django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader:
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Where is the code for your view itself?

Comment: Im just using the direct_to_template function in my urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `PROJECT_ROOT` to:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

And make sure your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` variable is set properly.

**Explanation:**

`abspath` gives you the full path of the `base.py`, i.e., `/home/some-path/project-folder/settings/base.py`

Therefore, first `dirname` gives you the dir path name of the given path (obtained above), i.e., `/home/some-path/project-folder/settings/`

And then, the second `dirname` gives you the dir path name of the given path (obtained above), i.e., `/home/some-path/project-folder/`

So, now when you join this path to `templates`, everything starts working fine.

For more refer [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks for generously donating your time to this issue. This solution worked instantly.Would you mind explaining why this solution worked so I can add this to my toolbox?

Comment: Ya... Definitely... I am adding the explanation to the answer itself.

Comment: Hey Sandip so based on the above scheme how should my STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS variable be updated? Havent been able to get my static assets implemented.

Comment: @harristrader Have you served your static files by specifying their urls? Moreover, please specify the problem situation here or creating a new question.

Answer (score 8):

All answers above require of configuring TEMPLATE_DIRS or TEMPLATE_LOADERS, which is not necessary and correct. You just have to put YOUR application to the INSTALLED_APPS.

For example, if your application is in the MyMegaApp (where settigs.py resides), in other words you have a project structure like below

```
MyMegaApp
   MyMegaApp
      templates
         index.html
      settings.py 
   manage.py
```

Then you have to add your app like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'MyMegaApp'
)
```

After that your **index.html** template will be found in **MyMegaApp/templates** folder

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is, in your settings, your `PROJECT_ROOT` evaluates to the directory which runs `manage.py`.

You may do this for `TEMPLATE_DIRS` settings

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
print PROJECT_ROOT
```

Now, append `../../` relative to the `PROJECT_ROOT`. Something like this:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../../'))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

can you test as below?

i think your code would set PROJECT_ROOT as '/some/path/to/settings'

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath, normpath, join
PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
normpath(join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this in settings

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'appname/templates'),

)
```

Add this to urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from  django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template import direct_to_template
from appname.views import *
```

call url by

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^foo/$',             'direct_to_template', {'template': 'foo_index.html'}),
    (r'^foo/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'foo_detail.html'}),
  )
```