# Django can't find templates, file exists and specified TEMPLATE_DIR

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I know there are lots of these questions already but I haven't been able to find an answer. I'm trying to get my homepage to load but I have been getting this error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.7.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
base.html
Exception Location: /Users/user/.virtualenvs/screen_savers/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 136
Python Executable:  /Users/user/.virtualenvs/screen_savers/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/user/Devspace/scren_savers/the_screen_savers',
 '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/screen_savers/lib/python34.zip',
 '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/screen_savers/lib/python3.4',
 '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/screen_savers/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/screen_savers/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/screen_savers/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

and can't seem to figure out why. I specified my `TEMPLATE_DIR` properly in my settings.py and made sure that the file exists where is says it does. I have also looked through all of these questions where people had the same problem but none of them solved my problem:

[Django App template Loader, can't find app templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552304/django-app-template-loader-cant-find-app-templates)

[Django template Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038459/django-template-path)

[Django can't find template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422469/django-cant-find-template)

[Django TemplateDoesNotExist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist)

[Template does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168256/template-does-not-exist)

[Django cant find templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452115/django-cant-find-templates)

What really confuses me is that if I check the value of BASE_DIR and TEMPLATE_DIR it gives me:

`/Users/user/Devspace/scren_savers/the_screen_savers`
`/Users/user/Devspace/scren_savers/the_screen_savers/templates`

respectively which is exactly what I expect to see. It seems like it knows where the templates are but still can't see them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also an additional, less important question:

I have seen `BASE_DIR + '/templates'` and `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")` suggested as the proper way to specify the `TEMPLATE_DIR`. Is one of these better than the other (if so why) or is this just a matter of personal preference?

Here is the view that I am trying to load:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

class home_page(View):

    def get(self, request):
       return render(request, 'base.html')
```

and here is my settings file:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIR =  (
    BASE_DIR +  "/templates/",
)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'screen_savers',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'screen_savers.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'screen_savers.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change in file settings.py TEMPLATE_DIR to TEMPLATE_DIRS.